# Twisted daemon unittest

Tags: python, twisted, daemon

I've started a client/server project at work using Twisted (I'm a newcomer, so not much experience). I probably did setup things the wrong way/order, because now I'm a little stuck with a Daemon server (using twistd --python to launch it).

I'm wondering if I've to re-implement the server as a standard process to use it in my unittest module?

Here's part of the code to launch the server as a Daemon in the server module (you'll probably recognize part of [krondo](http://krondo.com/blog)'s articles in this):

```
class TwistedHawkService(service.Service):
    def startService(self):
        ''''''
        service.Service.startService(self)
        log.msg('TwistedHawkService running ...')


# Configuration
port = 10000
iface = 'localhost'

topService = service.MultiService()

thService = TwistedHawkService()
thService.setServiceParent(topService)

factory = ReceiverFactory(thService)

tcpService = internet.TCPServer(port, factory, interface=iface)
tcpService.setServiceParent(topService)

application = service.Application("TwistedHawkService")

topService.setServiceParent(application)
```

I tried copy/pasting the configuration part in the setUp method:

```
from mfxTwistedHawk.client import mfxTHClient
from mfxTwistedHawk.server import mfxTHServer


class RequestTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Configuration
        port = 10000
        iface = 'localhost'

        self.topService = service.MultiService()

        thService = mfxTHServer.TwistedHawkService()
        thService.setServiceParent(self.topService)

        factory = mfxTHServer.ReceiverFactory(thService)

        tcpService = internet.TCPServer(port, factory, interface=iface)
        tcpService.setServiceParent(self.topService)

        application = service.Application("TwistedHawkService")

        self.topService.setServiceParent(application)

    def test_connection(self):
        mfxTHClient.requestMain('someRequest')
```

... but of course using *trial unittest.py* doesn't start it a daemon, so my client can't reach it.

Any advice of how to setup things would be appreciated.

Thanks!

**Edit:**
Managed to make everything works with this and [this](http://www.cs.lth.se/EDA046/assignments/assignment4/twisted/policy/test-standard.html), but still feel unsure about the whole thing:

```
def setUp(self):
    # Configuration
    port = 10000
    iface = 'localhost'

    service = mfxTHServer.TwistedHawkService()
    factory = mfxTHServer.ReceiverFactory(service)
    self.server = reactor.listenTCP(port, factory, interface=iface)
```

Is it ok to have a daemon implementation for production and standard process for unittest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it ok to have a daemon implementation for production and standard process for unittest?

Your unit test isn't for Twisted's daemonization functionality.  It's for the custom application/protocol/server/whatever functionality that you implemented.  In general, in a unit test, you want to involve as **little** code as possible.  So in general, it's quite okay, and even preferable, to have your unit tests **not** daemonize.  In fact, you probably want to write some unit tests that don't even listen on a real TCP port, but just call methods on your service, factory, and protocol classes.